# How does Meteor's package.js work?

Tags: meteor

[This Meteor.com blog post](http://meteor.com/blog/2013/04/04/meteor-060-brand-new-distribution-system-app-packages-npm-integration) talks about `package.js`. Is this similar or even the same as a `package.json` file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `package.js` file is used specifically with Meteor. If you browse through the repo at https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/packages you could see what a few look like. Each package has its own `package.js`.

`package.json` is slightly different, it's used to store node's `npm` dependencies so that one can run `npm install` to get the project's dependencies in order. It's more specific to npm/node than meteor. It wouldn't be used with meteor because meteor's `run` looks for dependencies defined with `Npm.depends` in the package's `package.js` for a particular package and gets the `npm` modules installed instead. So with meteor projects (apart from a bundled tarball in which they are automatically generated) don't need `package.json` files